# Html is not updating on ajax request (woordpress, woocomerce)

Tags: html, ajax, wordpress

When I filter products ajax only works the first time. After that HTML is just not updating.
https://gyazo.com/6acc69cdda75fdc737513ff92645c2cb

This is ajax response when I filter second time: https://pastebin.pl/view/63e67f8c
https://gyazo.com/81db697b0d7e556bc24d1bf635b70ffa

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved, the error messages, and your debugging attempt

Answer (score 0):

solved with updating php version

Answer (score 0):

It will be solved when you update the PHP version

It will surely help!
Thanks